# How to stop two divs from pushing each other on window resize

Tags: html, css

So I was wondering how can I make the box stops exactly before it go through the text.
 The box is just floating under the text, I want to make it stop floating before it hits.

### Normal Size

[image: Normal Size]

### Window resized

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="program"></div>
<span class="but">
    <h2 class="zaglavie">CSGOFREEITEMS <span class="beta">0.5.1</span></h2> 
    <p class="opisanie"><b>Ultimate platform</b>. The easiest way to have fancy inventory. Get the item you want just in <b>seconds</b>.</p>

    <div class="buttons">
        <a class="button1" href="#above"></a>
        <a class="button2" href="#above"></a>
        <span style="float: right; color: white; margin-right: 2px; margin-top: 1px; font-size: 10.5px;">for only <b>$4.99</b>/month</span>
    </div>
</span>

<br>
```

CSS:

```
.but
{
position: absolute;
top: 90px; 
font-family: Verdana;
display: block;
}
.zaglavie 
{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color: #e5e5e5;
font-size: 31px;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
position: relative;
left: 70px;
top: 100px;
font-weight: 700;
}

.opisanie 
{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color: #fefefe;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
font-size: 16px;
left: 70px;
top: 90px;
position: relative;
width: 400px;
}

.buttons
{
margin-left: 70px;
margin-top: 120px;
width: 375px;
height: 57px;
}

.button1
{
display:block;
width: 227px;
height: 57px;
background-image: url(images/button1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
float: left;
}

.button2
{
display:block;
width: 136px;
height: 57px;
background-image: url(images/button2.png);
margin-left: 240px;
}

.program
{
display:block;
width: 665px;
height: 745px;
background-image: url(images/sosi2.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
right: 50px;
position: relative;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: that box looks like a background of something, can you put your entire code?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry. It's edited now :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#4fc7d9522497eba555377ed94d364ee3

[CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) are a good solution for your problem.

I made a simple snippet [here](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#33b7c057b7d290dc8d9f0a4277d98d62) to show you how they work. You can utilize them with your site to fix the problem.

[What I decided to do here](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#4fc7d9522497eba555377ed94d364ee3) is use `display: table;` and `table-cell` to center your elements.

I then used [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to change the element from `display: table;` to `display: block;`

In addition I change your program background image to an image element as it's easier to style and handle upon page resize.

I converted your images to [Base64 aka DataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) (because I'm on a tablet and it's easier to test without extra http requests.

Here's a very simple example of how you can solve your problem with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

You can [view this weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#4fc7d9522497eba555377ed94d364ee3) for a more extensive solution (ex `display: table;` and `table-cell`).

```css
.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  background: #93e9ff;
}
.right {
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: #47ffaf;
}

@media all and (min-height: 300px) {
  .left, .right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .left {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
  }
  .right {
    bottom: 0;
    top: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left content</div>
<div class="right">right content</div>
```

Comment: No worries man. I know what it's like to be busy myself. My pleasure

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap and you will have a nice responsive design for your page.

This is your code with bootstrap, without css and using the images in the HTML section:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset ="utf-8">

<!--Bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">  
<div class="row">

<!--you can change that numbers to adapt your page to another devices like tablets-->
<!--if you see, the numbers are a proportion of 12, in this case, 5:7 (check the last div)-->
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <span class="but">
            <h2 class="zaglavie">CSGOFREEITEMS <span class="beta">0.5.1</span></h2> 
            <p class="opisanie"><b>Ultimate platform</b>. The easiest way to have fancy inventory. Get the item you want just in <b>seconds</b>.</p>

            <div class="buttons">
                <a class="button1" href="#above"><img src="images/button1.png"></a>
                <a class="button2" href="#above"><img src="images/button2.png"></a>
                <span style="float: right; color: white; margin-right: 2px; margin-top: 1px; font-size: 10.5px;">for only <b>$4.99</b>/month</span>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
            <!--if you see, the numbers are a proportion of 12, in this case, 5:7-->
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/sosi2.png">
    </div>

</div>  <!-- end row -->
</div>  <!-- end container-fluid -->

</body>
```

You can implement your css from here and you will see that will be more easy and solid.

See http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cYWiU_HsgM  (a nice tutorial of Bootstrap 3)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz wow, i had never seen that point of view, anyways it's fixed up right now.